# given distribution function find the density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-theorem

I am confused about one trivial thing.

We have independent variables $X,Y,\beta$ where $X$ has a distribution function $F(x)$, $Y$ has $G(x)$ and $\beta$ is $Bin(1,p)$ distributed. Also $X,Y$ have densities $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ correspondingly. Clear enough $Z=\beta X+(1-\beta)Y$ has a distribution function $H(x)=pF(x)+(1-p)G(x)$. What is the density of $Z$?

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous, then clearly $h(x)=p*f(x)+(1-p)*g(x)$ is the density of $Z$ because $H'(x)=h(x)$ and by the fundamental theorem of calculus $\int_{-\infty}^{x}h(t)dt=H(x)$ for any $x$, which proves that $h(x)$ is a distribution function for $Z$.

But if $g(x)$ or $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x^*$ then $H'(x^*)=h(x^*)$ is not necessarily true (not clear whether $H(x)$  is at all differentiable at $x^*$). So $H(x)$ is not an antiderivative for $h(x)$ on $R$. How then do I show that $\int_{-\infty}^{x}h(t)dt=H(x)$ for any $x$, i.e. $h(x)$ is a density function for $Z$?

Comment: The continuity of the densities is off-topic. If X has PDF f and Y has PDF g, then Z has PDF h=pf+(1-p)g, always. Proof: H=pF+(1-p)G.

Comment: I guess you are right, I am just confused myself above. So if we have a r.v. $X$ with cdf $F$ and we have a function $f$ such that $F=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)dt$ for any $x$ ($f$ is not unique in this sense), then automatically $f$ is a pdf for $X$. By this talking $h(x)=p*f(x)+(1-p)*g(x)$ is a pdf for $Z$ because $H(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}p*f(t)+(1-p)*g(t)$ for any $x$, right?